# If AB - BA is positive semidefinite, then A and B have a common eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be complex $n \times n$ matrices, and suppose that $AB - BA$ is positive-semidefinite, so that for all $x$, $\langle (AB - BA) x , x \rangle \geq 0$. How do I show that $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector?

I can figure out how to do it in the special case when $AB - BA = 0$, but don't know where to start for the general case.